# Сокращение создания объектов C#

Tags: c#

У меня есть код:

```
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ToolStripMenuItem item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ToolStripMenuItem item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
ToolStripMenuItem item4 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

Можно ли как-нибудь сократить его, чтобы, например, написать `tItem item1 = new tItem()` ?

Comment: `var item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();`

Comment: Комбинировал способ Streletz и Qwertiy♦ с объявлением через запятую.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать синтаксис using as alias. Выглядеть это будет приблизительно как-то так:

```
using tItem = ToolStripMenuItem
```

Но, в данном случае всё же лучше так не делать. Оригинальное название класса `ToolStripMenuItem` более описательно, чем `tItem`. Также стоит учесть, что это всё-таки стандартный класс `WinForms` и подобный подход рано или поздно собьёт с толку не только вас, но и других людей, которые потом будут сопровождать ваш код.

Answer (score 5):

Ещё вариант в кучу

```
Func<ToolStripMenuItem> c = () => new ToolStripMenuItem();
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = c(), item2 = c(), item3 = c(), item4 = c(), item5 = c();
```

Ну или

```
Func<ToolStripMenuItem> c = () => new ToolStripMenuItem();
(var item1, var item2, var item3, var item4, var item5) = (c(), c(), c(), c(), c());
```

Comment: интересные способы...
мне понравилось

Comment: Забавно, хотя практическая применимость сомнительна)

Comment: @Qwertiy как и всех других ответов и вопроса вцелом. Я бы в таком случае использовал массив.

Comment: @tym32167, у var применяется почти везде, так что не согласен. Написание переменных через запятую непопулярно, но в некоторых случаях весьма удобно.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не про var или запятые, я про набор отдельных переменных vs массив

Comment: @tym32167, ну, массив не всегда нужен. Такие имена могут быть для примера. Например, может быть набор кнопок с разными действиями.

Comment: @Qwertiy тут может быть много чего. В моем примере тоже функция может быть заменена виртуальным методом и вуаля - штаны превращаются в элегантный порождающий паттерн :)

Answer (score 1):

Вместо длинного названия типа можно использовать `var`:

```
var item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
var item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
var item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
var item4 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

Answer (score 0):

Переменные одного типа можно объявлять через запутую:

```
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem(), item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem(), item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem(), item4 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```

При желании можно поделить на несколько строк (хотя я бы не стал):

```
ToolStripMenuItem item1 = new ToolStripMenuItem(), item2 = new ToolStripMenuItem(),
  item3 = new ToolStripMenuItem(), item4 = new ToolStripMenuItem();
```